# Boxplot Stats Out and DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, boxplot

Maybe asking a simple question. But finding it hard to solve. Please look at the following code:

The DataFrame is = FBF_Variance_Pivot
which has three columns: DateKey,Concat,Units

```
unique_Concats<-unique(FBF_Variance_Pivot$Concat)
return_DF<-integer()
for(i in 1:length(unique_Concats)) {
  temp_DF<-FBF_Variance_Pivot[FBF_Variance_Pivot$Concat==unique_Concats[i],]
  if(length(boxplot.stats(temp_DF$Units)$out)>0) {
    rem_dates<-temp_DF$DateKey[which(temp_DF$Units %in% unique(boxplot.stats(temp_DF$Units)$out))]
    return_DF<-rbind(return_DF,
                     cbind(rem_dates,unique_Concats[i]))
  }
}
```

All I'm trying to do here is save DateKey and Concats which are Outliers into another DataFrame which I intend to use for cross-verification.

The resultant DF = return_DF

Problem: This runs for 6-7 hours due to the loop.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: how big is your dataset?

Comment: My Dataset is 55 Lac rows in main DF = FBF_Variance_Pivot and 6.5 Lac Rows in unique_Concats

Comment: you should add your dataset (using dput(yourdataset)) to your post so we can test your code.